# Why am I missing providers in this transition?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'll give only one resolve provider as example but it happens in most of them.

The simplified state structure is as follows:

- `accounts` resolve: accountsFolders
- `accounts.content`
- `accounts.content.viewcontacts`
- `accounts.content.viewaccounts`
- `accounts.content.viewcontacts.details` resolve depends on accountsFolders
- `accounts.content.viewaccounts.details` resolve depends on accountsFolders

I can access `accounts.content.viewaccounts.details` directly and it will work;

I can access `accounts.content.viewaccounts.details` from any of its parents and it works;

But If I try to `access accounts.content.viewaccounts.details` from `accounts.content.viewcontacts` I get `unknown provider accountsFoldersProvider`.

I'm using $state.go for my transitions.

What will work is if I add

```
accountsFolders: function(accountsFolders) {
    return accountsFolders;
}
```

to every other resolve

You can easily understand why it's undesirable, especially considering there are about 10 other objects that have to behave like accountsFolders and the state tree is very big.

Further details: (written here to avoid crowding the comments)

`accounts` resolve contains

```
accountsFolders: function(accountsFoldersPromise, folderService) { 
    return new folderService.StandardFolderList(accountsFoldersPromise.data)
}
```

`account.content.viewcontacts.details` resolve contains

```
currentFolder: function(accountsFolders, $stateParams) { 
    return accountsFolders.findById($stateParams.folderId);
}
```

`accountsFolders` is used in other resolve objects as dependency but never overwritten.

Comment: Could you post your entire state definition tree so we can get a better look at it? Or at the very least, the nested tree structure for `accounts` That would be of great help here. I think the problem lies in `resolve` objects running in parallel and as such, if you have any resolves on the underlying states - a race condition can occur.

Comment: @KasperLewau I don't know if I can provide the exact structure anymore because it's been changed since I posted the question. I've created an almost duplicate branch starting with accounts.content.viewcontacts.accountdetails because it made more sense and we needed the viewcontacts state to be active. In the meantime can you explain the problem with resolves running in parallel or point me to a resource to study?

Comment: When you say that the resolve objects in `accounts.content.viewcontacts.details` **depends** on `accountsFolders`, have you defined the `accountsFolders` resolve object as a dependency to the substates resolve object? Before I post an answer regarding resolve objects running in parallel, it'd be good to know how you've applied the relationship between the parent state resolve and the childstate resolve(s).

Comment: Do you have a `resolve` property in `.details` views? Also could you show us you `accountsFolders` implementation? Maybe the answer lays within it?

Comment: @KasperLewau I've added the details to the original question.

Comment: @gorpacrate I do have a resolve property for the `.details` state but I don't understand what you mean by `accountsFolders` implementation. If you mean the resolve object, it's now posted in the question. If you mean the actual accountsFolders object, then I'm afraid that's not something I can post here.

Comment: @Bogdan Alright so you are in fact depending on the result of the `accountsFolders` resolve object, that rules out my initial thought about there not being a dependency specified for it and as such - the `currentFolder` resolve running in parallel and perhaps causing a race condition. I'll keep scratching my head for the time being!

Comment: Yeah that's what's making me scratch my head as well. It's even weirder that I can go from `.viewcontacts.details` to `.viewaccounts` (viewaccounts resolve also requires the `accountsFolders` object) but not to `.viewaccounts.details`

Comment: First question: why are you using ui-router? Second question: Can you reproduce the problem in plnkr? I feel like it'd be easy to reproduce.